# Is perceived time compressed or expanded while dreaming? (or does it match reality)

Tags: perception, methodology, dreams, time

I often dream long extended dreams. Sometimes I wonder if the timeline of the story of my dream occurs compressed, in a moment, or other times extended slowly over a long duration.

- Is there any way to scientifically detect this, and how would it be accomplished?
- Are there any prior examples of this study being performed?